# Python cpppo won't display string data type from PLC

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the [cpppo](https://github.com/pjkundert/cpppo) Python package installed and I have an ABLogix IO Server with `192.168.1.100` IP that I typically connect to it with different software (not python) as `192.168.1.100,1,0`.

**My problem is** I cannot get it to bring back the value of a tag on an accessible PLC when that tag's data type is set to `String` in the PLC RSLogix 5000 code. The string value I'm testing with is a 12 character alphanumeric string if that matters so `U123HTS76312`

**My question is** to know if someone can see maybe something I'm overlooking that will allow me to get the value from a tag where the PLC has it defined as a `String` data type?

> **Note:** According to the [README.org](https://github.com/pjkundert/cpppo/blob/master/README.org) in the `client.connector.get_attribute_single and .get_attributes_all` section, it states "To access Get Attribute data with CIP type conversion, use `cpppo.server.enip.get_attribute`’s `proxy` classes, instead."
>
> - I think using `for message in source.read([(TagName, "SSTRING")], portLink)` in the non-working example "**c.**" below is specifying the CIP
>     type but it doesn't work

- **Potential Related Issue:** [Problem reading/writing STRING data types](https://github.com/pjkundert/cpppo/issues/44)

  - I get this same error if I try to write a value so that's why I think it may be related.

    > ```
    > python -m cpppo.server.enip.client -a 192.168.1.100 "UL1_LOTCODE_STR_X=(STRING)123HFGR45678"
    >
    > 11-08 10:51:47.692 MainThread enip.cli WARNING  validate   Client Single Write Tag  UL1_LOTCODE_STR_X returned non-zero status: Status 255 [8455]
    >    UL1_LOTCODE_STR_X              <= ['123HFGR45678']: 'Status 255 [8455]'
    > ```

---

> ### *The Context Begins. . .*

### 1. It Works. . .

I have a tag named `UL1_TICKETWEIGHT_X` which is set as a `DINT` in the PLC logic that I get the correct sensor data value back from as expected using the below logic.

**Working Python Logic**

```
from cpppo.server.enip.get_attribute import proxy_simple, proxy
from datetime import datetime
import time

TagName = "UL1_TICKETWEIGHT_X"
host = "192.168.1.100"
portLink = "route_path = [{'link':1,'port':0}]"
source = proxy(host)

for message in source.read(TagName, portLink):
    val = message
    timestr = str(datetime.now())
    print([timestr, val])
```

**Output**

```
UL1_TICKETWEIGHT_X == 55000 
['2018-11-07 19:59:24.853017', [55000]]
```

---

### 2. It Doesn't Work. . .

I have a tag named `UL1_LOTCODE_STR_X` which is set as a `String` in the PLC logic that does not get back the correct data from the sensor with the various things I've tried below to show a few.

I did many other things and read over slews of the code in the files hoping I could figure out which class or method to use or what arguments to pass to what, and so forth.

I have also set the value of `UL1_LOTCODE_STR_X` to a `DINT` type value (it is still `String` type though at PLC level) such as `15` and it still has the same problem

**a. Non-Working Python Logic**

```
from cpppo.server.enip.get_attribute import proxy_simple, proxy
from datetime import datetime
import time

TagName = "UL1_LOTCODE_STR_X"
host = "192.168.1.100"
portLink = "route_path = [{'link':1,'port':0}]"
source = proxy(host)

for message in source.read(TagName, portLink):
    val = message
    timestr = str(datetime.now())
    print([timestr, val])
```

**Output (error)**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Desktop\Test.py", line 11, in <module>
    for message in source.read(TagName, portLink):
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\server\enip\get_attribute.py", line 431, in read
    for val,(sts,(att,typ,uni)) in reader:
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\server\enip\get_attribute.py", line 606, in read_details
    depth=self.depth, multiple=self.multiple, timeout=self.timeout )):
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\server\enip\client.py", line 1393, in operate
    for idx,dsc,req,rpy,sts,val in harvested:
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\server\enip\client.py", line 1258, in pipeline
    col     = next( harvester )
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\server\enip\client.py", line 1190, in harvest
    issued, self.collect( timeout=timeout )): # must be "lazy" zip!
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\server\enip\client.py", line 1115, in collect
    response,elapsed    = await( self, timeout=timeout )
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\server\enip\client.py", line 872, in await
    for response in cli: # if StopIteration raised immediately, defaults to {} signalling completion
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\server\enip\client.py", line 546, in __next__
    for mch,sta in engine:
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\automata.py", line 645, in run
    source=source, machine=machine, path=path, data=data, ending=ending ):
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\automata.py", line 1226, in delegate
    for which,target in submach: # 75% of runtime is spent inside 'run'
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\automata.py", line 645, in run
    source=source, machine=machine, path=path, data=data, ending=ending ):
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\automata.py", line 1226, in delegate
    for which,target in submach: # 75% of runtime is spent inside 'run'
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\automata.py", line 645, in run
    source=source, machine=machine, path=path, data=data, ending=ending ):
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\automata.py", line 1291, in delegate
    raise NonTerminal( "%s sub-machine terminated in a non-terminal state" % ( self ))
cpppo.automata.NonTerminal: ( data.( select.((noop)) ) ) sub-machine terminated in a non-terminal state
```

**b. Non-Working Python Logic**

```
from cpppo.server.enip.get_attribute import proxy_simple, proxy
from datetime import datetime
import time

TagName = "UL1_LOTCODE_STR_X"
host = "192.168.1.100"
portLink = "route_path = [{'link':1,'port':0}]"
source = proxy(host)

for message in source.read_details(TagName, portLink):
    val = message
    timestr = str(datetime.now())
    print([timestr, val])
```

**Output (error)**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Desktop\Test.py", line 12, in <module>
    for message in source.read_details(TagName, portLink):
TypeError: read_details() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

**c. Non-Working Python Logic**

```
from cpppo.server.enip.get_attribute import proxy_simple, proxy
from datetime import datetime
import time

TagName = "UL1_LOTCODE_STR_X"
host = "192.168.1.100"
portLink = "route_path = [{'link':1,'port':0}]"
source = proxy(host)

for message in source.read([(TagName, "SSTRING")], portLink):
    val = message
    timestr = str(datetime.now())
    print([timestr, val])
```

**Output (error)**

```
UL1_LOTCODE_STR_X == None 
['2018-11-08 00:05:48.424095', None]
```

**d. Non-Working Python Logic**

**Note:** *This works if I put a tag in as the argument with is not a `String` type within the PLC logic.*

```
python -m cpppo.server.enip.client -a 192.168.1.100 "UL1_LOTCODE_STR_X"
```

**Output (error)**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\server\enip\client.py", line 1649, in <module>
    sys.exit( main() )
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\server\enip\client.py", line 1630, in main
    fragment=fragment, printing=printing, timeout=timeout )
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\server\enip\client.py", line 1406, in process
    transactions                = list( self.results( operations=operations, **kwds ))
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\server\enip\client.py", line 1398, in results
    for idx,dsc,req,rpy,sts,val in self.operate( operations, **kwds ):
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\server\enip\client.py", line 1393, in operate
    for idx,dsc,req,rpy,sts,val in harvested:
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\server\enip\client.py", line 1283, in validate
    for index,descr,request,reply,status,val in harvested:
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\server\enip\client.py", line 1258, in pipeline
    col         = next( harvester )
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\server\enip\client.py", line 1190, in harvest
    issued, self.collect( timeout=timeout )): # must be "lazy" zip!
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\server\enip\client.py", line 1115, in collect
    response,elapsed    = await( self, timeout=timeout )
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\server\enip\client.py", line 872, in await
    for response in cli: # if StopIteration raised immediately, defaults to {} signalling completion
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\server\enip\client.py", line 546, in __next__
    for mch,sta in engine:
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\automata.py", line 645, in run
    source=source, machine=machine, path=path, data=data, ending=ending ):
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\automata.py", line 1226, in delegate
    for which,target in submach: # 75% of runtime is spent inside 'run'
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\automata.py", line 645, in run
    source=source, machine=machine, path=path, data=data, ending=ending ):
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\automata.py", line 1226, in delegate
    for which,target in submach: # 75% of runtime is spent inside 'run'
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\automata.py", line 645, in run
    source=source, machine=machine, path=path, data=data, ending=ending ):
  File "\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cpppo\automata.py", line 1291, in delegate
    raise NonTerminal( "%s sub-machine terminated in a non-terminal state" % ( self ))
cpppo.automata.NonTerminal: ( data.( select.((noop)) ) ) sub-machine terminated in a non-terminal state
```

---

### **Other Specs**

- **Python:** `3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]`
- **OS:** Windows 10

Comment: Let me know what I can add to help if I did something wrong please. My goal is to provide everything that's needed so please just tell me if I left something obvious or required out to make this a better question.

Comment: The error of `cpppo.automata.NonTerminal: ( data.( select.((noop)) ) ) sub-machine terminated in a non-terminal state` seems to pop up a lot so not sure if that'd be a helpful pointer for the automata.py file to see if it needs something updated to have the string type for the tag value or what.

Comment: We ended up sending the decimal value of each character's position in the string to an indexed tag (I think PLC array) and then translate that with a mapped table using MySQL as part of an import process to translate to the string characters. So if we have 10 characters in a string, we have 10 separate data points that it's character code decimal value is mapped back to the `[A-Z][a-z][0-9]` values. In case someone ever wonders what was done, that seemed to work best but the Python logic still works well for non-string characters.